# Import Python lib 'requests' in matlab not working

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

I'm using matlab 2016b and Python 2.7 in Mac OS x Sierra.

When I import `py.import.import_lib('requests')`, I'm getting a 'no module' python error. Same for 'web socket' too. But when I try to do the same in the terminal with same Python version, I'm getting the output.

I have tried the below solution but it is not working.

```
RTLD_NOW = 2;                      
RTLD_DEEPBIND = 8;         
flag = bitor(RTLD_NOW, RTLD_DEEPBIND);         
py.sys.setdlopenflags(int32(flag));        
py.importlib.import_module('requests');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to locate the missing python module with

```
import the_missing_module
import os
path = os.path.dirname(the_missing_module.__file__)
print path
```

and then check if the `path` is in the MATLAB Search Path subset.